# x-csrf-token validation fails on HttpPost

Tags: android, http, http-headers, odata, androidhttpclient

I have to post xml payload to an `ODATA` service which requires Authentication and `x-csrf-token`.

I have two `AsyncTasks`. In First one has `URLConnection` object and fetches `x-csrf-token` with code below:

```
 URL obj = new URL(Util.ODATA_URL + "SO_BEATPSet");
                    URLConnection conn = obj.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
                    conn.addRequestProperty("x-csrf-token", "fetch");

......
......

 String server = conn.getHeaderField("x-csrf-token");
```

Now, in Second `AsyncTask` executed right after the first one finishes succesfully, i encounter **403 error**. It bascially says that my **x-csrf-token validation has failed**.

I ran a simple looping test, where i ran the first `AsyncTask` three times, and i got three different tokens. 
That is where i think the problem is. When in Second `AsyncTask` I use `HttpPost`, the server is expecting a different token other than an already fetched one.

**Is there any way that i can fetch and pass the X-csrf-token in the same call?**
My Second AsyncTask is like below:

```
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);

String credentials = UUSERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD;
                    String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

postRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);
postRequest.addHeader("x-csrf-token", X_CSRF_TOKEN); //   JHc4mG8siXrDtMSx0eD9wQ==

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(XMLBuilders.BeatXMLBuilder());
entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader("Content-Type",
                            "application/atom+xml"));
postRequest.setEntity(entity);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was eventually able to get the successful POST result. However, the solution seems a bit dirty to me. But, it did sort out my problem for now.

I put the Code like below in `doInBackground()` method of `AsyncTask`

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);

 String credentials = USERNAME + ":" +PASSWORD;
 String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

  /**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- **/
  /** THIS CODE BELOW CALLS THE SERVER FOR THE TOKEN AND PASSES THE VALUE TO THE SUBSEQUENT POSTREQUEST CALL.
      BY DOING THIS, THE SERVER IS NOT CALLED AGAIN BEFORE POSTREQUEST, AND USER GETS THE LATEST TOKEN **/
                        {
                            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
                            httpget.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);
                            httpget.setHeader("x-csrf-token", "fetch");

                            System.out.println("request:-------------------");
                            System.out.println(httpget.getRequestLine());
                            Header headers[] = httpget.getAllHeaders();
                            for (Header h : headers) {
                                System.out.println(h.getName() + "---:---- " + h.getValue());
                            }

                            HttpResponse res = httpclient.execute(httpget);                           
                            System.out.println("response:-------------------");
                            System.out.println(res.getStatusLine());

                            headers = res.getAllHeaders();
                            for (Header h : headers) {
                                System.out.println(h.getName() + "---:---- " + h.getValue());
                                if (h.getName().equals("x-csrf-token")) {
                                    X_CSRF_TOKEN = h.getValue();
                                }
                            }
                        }
  /**--------------------------------------------------------------------- **/


    // The main POST REQUEST
     postRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);
     postRequest.setHeader("x-csrf-token", X_CSRF_TOKEN); //   PASSING THE TOKEN GOTTEN FROM THE CODE ABOVE


     StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(myString);
     entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader("Content-Type",
                                "application/atom+xml"));
     postRequest.setEntity(entity);


     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(postRequest);
     Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());

     String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
     Log.d("Http Response:", result);

     int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
     Log.d("Http Response: ", "Response code " + responseCode);
```

As I explain in the Code comments as well, the Code makes another call to the server while `HttpPost` has already made one and gets the latest token, which in turn is passed to the subsequent POST request.

Comment: I am calling API using retrofit and I have added   
               if (!Prefs.with().getString(ApiParamConstant.CSRF_TOKEN, "").isEmpty()) {
                        requestBuilder.header("X-Csrf-Token",
                                Prefs.with().getString(ApiParamConstant.CSRF_TOKEN, ""));
                    }

but its throwing 403

Do you have any solution using CSRF with retrofit?

Comment: This post was what helped me with a similar problem. I also did not realize that I need to use the same client both for the token GET request and the POST entity request, otherwise the second one would expect a different csrf token. Your solution helped me to understand the issue at hand, thanks! (I am using springframework to do the requests, but the idea remains the same)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried encoding or decoding x-csrf-token?

```
String tokenEncoded = URLEncoder.encode("xcsrftoken", "UTF-8")

String tokenDecoded = URLDecoder.decode("xcsrftoken", "UTF-8");
```

I once had similar issues using encoding did the trick for me.

Comment: The issue actually is that Token value itself changes.

Comment: You have to get new token value and write it to preference everytime you make an http request in that case.

Comment: I've got the solution and will post it soon. I tried the way you said using storing it, but that was not my problem at all.